# Normal distribution with a probability less than 0.1?

Tags: probability-distributions

The question states, "find the value of c where Z has a normal distribution with u=0 and variance=1

P(-2.7 < Z < c) = 0.0252

How do I find the c value for this problem?

Comment: This would be a better question if you showed what you tried and explained how you got stuck. Have you learned how to use a standard normal distribution table? Here is a link to one, and most of the probabilities on the first page of the table are less than $0.1$: http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- $\mathbb P(-2.7 < Z < c) = \mathbb P(Z \lt c) - \mathbb P(Z \le -2.7)$
- You can find $\mathbb P(Z \le -2.7)$
- and then find $c$ such that $\mathbb P(Z \lt c) = \mathbb P(Z \le -2.7) + 0.0252$

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that help.  I have learnt to use a normal distribution table.  I did the following working, bearing in mind your suggestion and got the question right:

P (Z < c) - 1 + 0.9965 = 0.0252
= P (Z < c) - 0.0035 = 0.0252
  Therefore P(Z < c) = 0.0287          If d = (1 - c), 
       Then P(Z < c) = 0.9713
  Which means that d = 1.90

Therefore c = -1.90

This was the correct answer in the textbook